# Command to Unlock a locked domain user

Tags: powershell, dns, directory, command, locked

I'v been using these to list locked users in my domain and prompt me  for input samaccountname to unlock desired one:
I did it with 3 file.

first one is ps1 to list all of them

```
    import-module activedirectory
    search-adaccount -lockedout | select  name, samaccountname, OU
```

second one is another ps1 file:

```
    $user = Read-Host "Enter user account (SAMACCOUNTNAME) to unlock or press ENTER to refresh list"
    Search-ADAccount -LockedOut | Where {$_.samaccountname -eq $user} | Unlock-ADAccount
```

and for executing above files, i use a .bat file:

```
    :loop
    powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File c:\ps\lockedlist.ps1
    powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File c:\ps\unlock.ps1
    cls
    goto loop
```

and when i run it... it list all locked users and i can copy paste each samaacount name to unlock them

BUT the problem is,when I want to do it with ONE ps1 file it doesnt work. it just ask for samaccountname but it doesnt list it

```
    import-module activedirectory
    search-adaccount -lockedout | select  name, samaccountname, OU
    $user = Read-Host "Enter user account (SAMACCOUNTNAME) to unlock or press ENTER to refresh list"
    Search-ADAccount -LockedOut | Where {$_.samaccountname -eq $user} | Unlock-ADAccount
```

i know .bat file will be pretty same...

thanks to anyone who reads and helps.

Comment: Why do you run the search for the locked out accounts twice? Actually all you need would be something like this: `Search-ADAccount -LockedOut | Unlock-ADAccount`!?

Comment: BTW: "__OU__" is not an attribute you get as aoutput from the cmdlet `Search-ADAccount`. You could get the "__DistinguishedName__".

Comment: An idea to the behaviour you experience with your script. Powershell always tries to "_optimize_" the output for you. So the output Powershell produced does not have to be the same order like the commands you run. If you'd put a `Format-Table` behind your initial `Search-ADAccount` you'll get the desired output.

Comment: i use Search-ADAccount -LockedOut twice: one to list all of locked users
and second time to unlock user that i find from list

Comment: Format-Table   didnt work. can u explain more? maybe im doing it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powershell always tries to optimize the output it gives for you. So the order of the output might not be the same as you expect it from the commands you have in a script. If possible it will concatenate output to be more readable especially when it's the same type of objects. To break this you could use a format cmdlet like `Format-Table` par example.

```
Search-ADAccount -LockedOut | 
    Select-Object -Property Name, sAMAccountName, DistinguishedName |
        Format-Table
$user = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter user account (SAMACCOUNTNAME) to unlock or press ENTER to refresh list'
Search-ADAccount -LockedOut | 
    Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.samaccountname -eq $user} | 
        Unlock-ADAccount
```

At least, it worked in my environment. 
And BTW: Since Powershell version 3 you don't need to explicitly import the modules anymore. They will be imported automaticaly. Better would be to use a [#Requires](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires?view=powershell-6) statement like `#Requires -Modules activedirectory` on top of the script. That would even prevent the script to run if there's no active directory module installed